# How to change the frame rate of a core animation instance?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-animation

Take CABasicAnimation for example. How do you lower the frame rate (overhead)? Animations run smooth, but my touchesMoved method skips a beat. Want to reduce the animation frame rate so touchesMoved is not skipping movements.

Comment: I am not sure if the use case above (reducing frame rate during interaction) is the best, but there are others. I have several mostly decorative animations where being able to say halve the frame rate would be a useful option for users on battery powered devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any inherent control over frame rate once you start your CABasicAnimation.

Probably the best way to achieve this would be to create multiple interpolations for a single animation (i.e. if you're moving 50 px down and 50px across, do 2 x 25px each) and induce an artificial sleep in your thread.  Not a perfect solution, but will perhaps achieve slightly better results that you're seeing.

Be aware that this technique will have different framerates on different CPUs, and is therefore not generally recommended.  Essentially, YMMV.

Comment: Note that this technique would add overhead and work against animation timing functions.