# Is there a way to set the number of animation steps for CABasicAnimation?

Tags: iphone, core-animation, calayer, cabasicanimation

I want to create an animation that interpolates some property for 2 seconds and only 20 frames (presentation layers) have to be generated by the CoreAnimation framework. I know how to provide a duration for the explicit animation but which property do I have to change in order to get particular number of frames calculated by interpolation process?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core Animation works by using interpolation--calculating intermediate values in between key values you specify. If it's a keyframe animation, it interpolates between the number (n) of values in your values array. If it's a basic animation, it interpolates between two values--your start and end values. If you just want to change the frame rate of the animation instance go through this [How to change the frame rate of a core animation instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670683/how-to-change-the-frame-rate-of-a-core-animation-instance)

Comment: Thanks to your answer, it looks like I found the way to go around this problem. I created CAKeyframeAnimation and set kCAAnimationDiscrete for it's calculationMode property. In this case, CA won't actually interpolate but it will change the value by descreete steps according the values array. The number of steps depends on how many elements I put in that array. So i'd say your answer is "almost" correct. I'm new to stackoverfow. What's the common practice in this case? Should I edit other's posts without their permission?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not possible with Core Animation. The number of times it draws your layer is based off your program's frame rate.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I thouht like that but CAKeyFrameAnimation seems to me the nice way to create animation with bit more control.

Comment: I see how you can do what you want in your response to the other answer. Sorry for my bad answer.